# Does facebook gives you realtime update when user revoke permission to your App?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a Facebook App (the one hosted in iframe). In a scenario I cache user's permission in database, and rely on Facebook Realtime Update to keep my permissions cache in sync.

I notice that when user approve my app, Facebook does send POST to my Realtime endpoint. However, when user revoke a permission, there is no update.

Is it by design or I miss something?

In Facebook App setting I've subscribed to permission object and leave the fields as empty.

Troy

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried them yet but I would suggest if you could also give a look to [Realtime Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) feature. It has the options of getting notified when there are changes in the permissions the user has granted your application

Comment: thanks. I'm actually asking about Realtime Update. I've set up all the required endpoints. I can receive GET validation and POST update for things such as "user likes". Just no permission revoke updates.

Comment: You have to use the permissions object with the fields listing out permission you want to be notified about for to get realtime update on it.

Comment: Please be noted in my original post I said I can receive POST notification when user "approve" permission to my App. In other words, my setting is correct. It just doesn't receive "permission revoke" notification. So I specifically doubt if Facebook doesn't sent you notification when permission is revoked. That is my ask.

Comment: In your original post you have mentioned that you have subscribed to them but have left the field empty, what I was suggesting earlier is to add the permissions you have asked in those fields, then only will you get the POST on change with those permissions. And to be clear I haven't tried it but will try it now to get clear on its working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a Deauthorize Callback URL in your app settings. It's in the advanced session.
When a user revokes your app authoriztion, FB will make a POST to the specified url.

[This might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670293/how-to-use-deauthorize-callback-url-with-facebook-js-sdk)

Comment: Deauthorize only happens when the user uninstalls the app.  The user can apparently remove some permissions (e.g. publish_actions) without uninstalling the app: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications